# Formatting citations in bibtex4word

Tags: bibtex, msword

I am using bibtex4word to manage my references in Word 2010. I am using "agsm/(l3yshp;" as the style, so that my references appears in by surname-year format.

The citations work well once they are at the end of a sentence (e.g. the existing research focused on X (Han et al., 2003) ). However, if the sentence has to contain the names of the researchers specifically (e.g. Han et al. (2003) showed the importance of X) then I have to manually adjust the citation as it alwalys prints the citations in brackets. The problem is, whenever I print such an adjusted citation (either as a print-out or as a pdf), the citation prints *without* my manual adjustment.

[On their web-page](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/), a similar question is posed with the title 'Parentheses adjacent to a citation disappear when I refresh the bibliography', but I could not make it work?!

Comment: I'm not sure how much help you will be able to find on this site.  This sounds like a problem with the program itself, and nothing to do with BibTeX per se.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Yes, I also thought similarly, but I hoped someone might have come across and found a round-about to solve this problem. I also come up with few ideas: rephrasing the sentences so that citations go to the end or writing the citations manually.

Comment: I would try to contact the developer and see if he is willing to add such a feature to the program.  (I don't use Windows, so I can't even test how well the program works, unfortunately....)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use "agsm/l3yshp" instead of "agsm/(l3yshp" and then add the brackets wherever you need them. This should export you the brackets only where needed i.e. typed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

Eventually, what I had done is to write all my citations/references by using Zotero's Word plugin. I think Zotero is better than bibtex4word; because, 
1. No need for manual adjustment (adding or removing parentheses) once the references are generated. 
2. URL's last visited date appears in the references, something which is not supported in bibtex4word.